# pythonのオブジェクト指向のエラー

Tags: python, python-idle

```
class Orange:
        def _init_ (self,w,c):
            self.weight=w
            self.color=c
            print("Created!")

or1=Orange(10,"dark")
```

`TypeError:  Orange() takes no argument` と出てしまいます。どこが違うのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pythonのコンストラクタは `_init_` ではなく `__init__` です。

Comment: なるほど!picosushiさん回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: この回答でよろしければ、✓（解決としてマーク）をお願いします。